# React 18 Rendering Before setState causing error

Tags: reactjs, fetch

So I've been trying to make super simple api request like the following and store it into a useState var, however after the recent update to React 18, I get an error before anything can render because str returns as undefined. It is not a failure to return data from the api but str returning as undefined because it is not waiting for the state of data to be set.

I am not sure of what to do because in previous versions of React, I have not had this problem. Has anyone figured out what could possible be the issue? I checked the docs but there doesn't seem to be any mention of this being something to be aware of.

```
const Component = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
      const str = data.data.sentence

          useEffect(() => {
            fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/sentences/2")
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => setData(data));
          }, []);
       
       return (
         <div> 
            <p>{str}</p>
         </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of react. You just need to handle the case for "What do I show when I haven't gotten the data back yet?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `data.data.sentence` is undefined when you declare it as `str` the whole component will throw an error. So you need to set it as it could be null.

```js
const str = data?.data.sentence
```

This has always been the case with older versions of React so you were probably doing something else.

I personally would have a loading state in there so you wouldn't render `str` without there being a value.

```js
const Component = () => {

      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
      const str = data.data.sentence

          useEffect(() => {
            fetch("https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/sentences/2")
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => setData(data));
          }, []);

       if(!str){
          return 'loading'
       }
       
       return (
         <div> 
            <p>{str}</p>
         </div> 
    )
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. When I tell you this set me back literal hours.

THANK,
YOU,
SIR!